# Attach a file to an email while sending it using an API

Tags: aws-lambda, python-requests, mailgun

I am using this API to send email using amazon lambda.

https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html

This works as expected, but I am not able to send an attachment.

```
def handler(event,context):

  import requests, os

  tempurl = event['url']
  myReq = requests.get(tempurl)
  email = event.get('email', 'my.name@gmail.com')
  title = event.get('title', 'emailThis')
  params = {"from": "Excited User <excited-user@example.com>", "to": email, "subject": title, "html": myReq.text}

  requests.post(os.environ['myUrl'] + '/messages', auth=("api", os.environ['myAuth'] ), data=params)
```

How do I attach a file from lambda's local environment?
I am creating a file using this code...

```
import tempfile
temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
temp.write(b'Hello world!')
temp.close()
```

The 'temp' file needs to be attached in post request mentioned above.

Comment: Is there any easier method to send attachments from Lambda function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send an email with an attachment using the [Mailgun Email API](https://www.mailgun.com/products/send/email-api/) in an AWS Lambda function, you will need to modify your existing code to include the attachment as part of the HTTP `POST` request. In Python, you can use the [`requests` library](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) to accomplish this task by including a `files` parameter in the `requests.post` call.

```py
def handler(event, context):
    import requests, os
    import tempfile

    # Fetch the email template
    tempurl = event['url']
    myReq = requests.get(tempurl)

    # Create a temporary file
    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    temp.write(b'Hello world!')
    temp.seek(0)

    # Email configuration
    email = event.get('email', 'my.name@gmail.com')
    title = event.get('title', 'emailThat')
    params = {"from": "Excited User <excited-user@example.com>", "to": email, "subject": title, "html": myReq.text}

    # Attach the temporary file
    with open(temp.name, 'rb') as attachment:
        files = {'attachment': ('tempfile.txt', attachment)}
        requests.post(
            os.environ['myUrl'] + '/messages',
            auth=("api", os.environ['myAuth']),
            data=params,
            files=files
        )

    # Close and remove the temporary file
    temp.close()
    os.unlink(temp.name)
```

The temporary file is created using `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)` so that we can use its name later. The `files` dictionary specifies the name of the attachment (`'tempfile.txt'`) as it will appear in the email and the file object itself (`attachment`).

After the `POST` request, the temporary file is closed and removed from the Lambda environment to prevent any resource leak.

```py
requests.post(
    os.environ['myUrl'] + '/messages',
    auth=("api", os.environ['myAuth']),
    data=params,
    files=files
)
```

The specific API endpoint for sending messages is generally `/messages`, and that is what the `requests.post` call is targeting in the `os.environ['myUrl'] + '/messages'` URL. The auth parameter is used for authentication using your Mailgun Email API key, which is stored in the environment variable `os.environ['myAuth']`.

The `data=params` includes the essential email details such as the sender, recipient, subject, and HTML content. Finally, the `files=files` parameter is where the attachment is added to the email.

---

> Is there any easier method to send attachments from Lambda function?

A possible alternative approach to send attachments from an AWS Lambda function would be to use [AWS Simple Email Service (SES)](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) along with the [AWS SDK for Python, known as Boto3](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/). Since both Lambda and SES are AWS services, the integration is relatively straightforward, and you may find it easier to manage your resources within the AWS ecosystem.
See also "**[Boto3: AWS SDK for Python, Introduction:](https://medium.com/featurepreneur/boto3-aws-sdk-for-python-e7391b9901c5)**" from [Sivaraam T K](https://twitter.com/Blazekiller69).

```py
import boto3
import os
import base64
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

def handler(event, context):

    # Initialize AWS SES client
    ses_client = boto3.client('ses')

    # Create a temporary file
    temp_file_content = b'Hello world!'
    attachment = MIMEApplication(temp_file_content)
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment', filename='tempfile.txt')

    # Create a multipart email message
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = event.get('title', 'emailThat')
    msg['From'] = "Excited User <excited-user@example.com>"
    msg['To'] = event.get('email', 'my.name@gmail.com')

    # Add HTML body to the email
    tempurl = event['url']
    myReq = requests.get(tempurl)
    part = MIMEText(myReq.text, 'html')
    msg.attach(part)

    # Attach the file to the email
    msg.attach(attachment)

    # Send the email
    response = ses_client.send_raw_email(
        Source=msg['From'],
        Destinations=[msg['To']],
        RawMessage={
            'Data': msg.as_string(),
        }
    )

    return response
```

The AWS Boto3 SDK is used to interact with the SES service. The Python `email.mime` modules are used to create a multipart email message that includes both the HTML body and the file attachment. The `send_raw_email` method sends the assembled email.

Note that you would need to install the Boto3 library in your Lambda environment and also make sure the SES service is set up correctly, including email address verification if necessary.

That should offer a relatively straightforward way to send attachments from a Lambda function.